# Bukkit Config - get Subsections and safe casting

Tags: java, plugins, configuration, minecraft, bukkit

I have the following config file:

```
arenas
  arena1
    info: infotest
    info2: info2test
  arena2
    info: infotest
    info2: info2test
```

So. Now i want to get one arena, and convert it to a arena object, i have a constructor there taking a Map. So i do following:

```
Arena a = new Arena((Map<String, Object>) getConfig().get("arenas.arena1"));
```

That is working. But: im getting the following warning in eclipse:

```
Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object to Map<String,Object>
```

I undestand why this apperas. but how can i change the way getting the informations to avoid this, so to make a "safe" cast?

And my second question: Now i want to get all the sub Map 's from arenas.""
and initialize them when the plugin loads. How can i get all of them? I cannot find something like arenas.getAll() or i dont know.. something like this.. anyone an idea?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question, you can get the configuration section "arena1" and get all of the values as a Map without any warnings. To do this, use:

```
config.getConfigurationSection("arenas.arena1").getValues(false);
```

Alternatively, you can just put `@SupressWarnings("unchecked")` over the method where you're using that code. Since you know the type you're getting will be a Map, the warning doesn't really mean much, though some developers might consider this bad practice.

For your second question, you can use a similar method. getValues() is essentially a getAll() type of method, it gets a map of all of the keys and values in the section. So you could use:

```
config.getConfigurationSection("arenas").getValues(false);
```